# i tried to install ojet-cli globlay like Oracle said on linux ubuntu but ojet command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, oracle-jet

I've Ubuntu OS 18.04 LTS , 
  npm: '6.4.1',
  ares: '1.14.0',
  cldr: '32.0.1',
  http_parser: '2.7.1',
  icu: '60.2',
  modules: '57',
  nghttp2: '1.30.0',
  node: '8.10.0',
  openssl: '1.1.0g',
  tz: '2017c',
  unicode: '10.0',
  uv: '1.18.0',
  v8: '6.2.414.50',
  zlib: '1.2.11'  .

When ojet-cli installation process finished fine without any complain, but ojet command not found also, when i tried this command

> npm list -g ojet-cli

output

> ~$ npm list -g @oracle/ojet-cli
>   /home/tsam/.npm-global/lib
>
> └── ojet-cli@3.2.0

also tried to install ojet-cli package many times also tried to install npm
by this command "useless"

> sudo npm install npm

nothing happen

another thing : i tried to run this command

> npm run ojet

output :

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
>   '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'ojet' ] 2 info using npm@6.4.1 3 info
>   using node@v8.10.0 4 verbose config Skipping project config:
>   /home/tsam/.npmrc. (matches userconfig) 5 verbose stack Error: ENOENT:
>   no such file or directory, open '/home/tsam/package.json' 6 verbose
>   cwd /home/tsam 7 verbose Linux 4.15.0-36-generic 8 verbose argv
>   "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "ojet" 9 verbose node
>   v8.10.0 10 verbose npm  v6.4.1 11 error path /home/tsam/package.json
>   12 error code ENOENT 13 error errno -2 14 error syscall open 15 error
>   enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/home/tsam/package.json' 16 error enoent This is related to npm not
>   being able to find a file. 17 verbose exit [ -2, true ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :**

> ojet command not found

***Cause :*** 
npm install packages  in location not match executed command path,
when checked npm configuration by

> npm config get

I found it

> prefix = "/home/tsam/.npm-global"

***Solution :***

change environment path to this path + /bin like that

> export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin

to make this configuration permanent , you have to change it from

*~/.profile* file and save it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer your own question, this might definitely help someone in the future